# Curved edges on Activity android

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I am trying to create a pop-up window with curved edges. I saw there is an existing question similar to this from a year ago with many answers that I tried out and none of which solve the problem at hand. Ultimately, I am creating an activity that will have curved edges itself, however, there is a white background that has corners beneath it so the effect does not work. Additionally, I am trying to display this over my other activity using Intents but this creates a whole new screen and blacks out the space not taken by the activity. I really appreciate the help, thank you.[image: This is what the activity looks like right now]

XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
        <corners
            android:radius="25dp"
            />
        <solid
            android:color="@color/GreenYellow"/>


</shape>
```

JAVA code initializing the window:

```
confirmLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.confirm_window);
    getWindow().setLayout(width,height);
    confirmLayout.setGravity(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    confirmLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.justcurves);
```

XML for window itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/confirm_window"
tools:context="com.exampleryancocuzzo.ryan.markettycoon.ConfirmWindow"
android:background="@color/GreenYellow"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Press Confirm to proceed"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Confirm"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:onClick="confirmed"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:background="@color/DarkGray"
    android:onClick="cancelled"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

For make the activity with curved edges, you can define your own theme in the styles.xml..!

Please check the below example to get some idea about it,

**rounded_drawable.xml**

```
<corners android:radius="15dp" />

<solid android:color="#565656" />

<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#ffffff" />

<padding
    android:bottom="6dp"
    android:left="6dp"
    android:right="6dp"
    android:top="3dp" />
```

Next make your own theme that extends the parent `Theme.Dialog` in **styles.xml**:

```
<style name="ThemeWithCorners" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/another_test_drawable</item>
</style>
```

and in the **manifest**, add your theme in the activity tag,

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeWithCorners" >
```

Thats all!
For more info about the styles, you can refer the the below url:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I tried this concept and I got an IllegalStateException for not using a Theme.AppCompat theme in the activity

Comment: You need to extend your activity class to `android.app.Activity` or the second option is to replace `android:Theme.Dialog` in styles.xml with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`

Answer (score 0):

My app extended AppCompatActivity, which threw an IllegalStateException, but works once I changed the superclass to Activity